# R profiling spending a lot of time using .External2

Tags: r, performance, profiling

I am learning how to use R profiling, and have run the `Rprof` command on my code.

The `summaryRprof` function has shown that a lot of time is spent using `.External2`. What is this? Additionally, there is a large proportion of the total time spent on `<Anonymous>`, is there a way to find out what this is?

```
> summaryRprof("test")
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
".External2"                 4.30    27.74       4.30     27.74
"format.POSIXlt"             2.70    17.42       2.90     18.71
"which.min"                  2.38    15.35       4.12     26.58
"-"                          1.30     8.39       1.30      8.39
"order"                      1.16     7.48       1.16      7.48
"match"                      0.58     3.74       0.58      3.74
"file"                       0.44     2.84       0.44      2.84
"abs"                        0.40     2.58       0.40      2.58
"scan"                       0.30     1.94       0.30      1.94
"anyDuplicated.default"      0.20     1.29       0.20      1.29
"unique.default"             0.20     1.29       0.20      1.29
"unlist"                     0.18     1.16       0.20      1.29
"c"                          0.16     1.03       0.16      1.03
"data.frame"                 0.14     0.90       0.22      1.42
"structure"                  0.12     0.77       1.74     11.23
"as.POSIXct.POSIXlt"         0.12     0.77       0.12      0.77
"strptime"                   0.12     0.77       0.12      0.77
"as.character"               0.08     0.52       0.90      5.81
"make.unique"                0.08     0.52       0.16      1.03
"[.data.frame"               0.06     0.39       1.54      9.94
"<Anonymous>"                0.04     0.26       4.34     28.00
"lapply"                     0.04     0.26       1.70     10.97
"rbind"                      0.04     0.26       0.94      6.06
"as.POSIXlt.POSIXct"         0.04     0.26       0.04      0.26
"ifelse"                     0.04     0.26       0.04      0.26
"paste"                      0.02     0.13       0.92      5.94
"merge.data.frame"           0.02     0.13       0.56      3.61
"[<-.factor"                 0.02     0.13       0.52      3.35
"stopifnot"                  0.02     0.13       0.04      0.26
".deparseOpts"               0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
".External"                  0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"close.connection"           0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"doTryCatch"                 0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"is.na"                      0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"is.na<-.default"            0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"mean"                       0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"seq.int"                    0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"sum"                        0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13
"sys.function"               0.02     0.13       0.02      0.13

$by.total
                        total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"write.table"                 5.10     32.90      0.00     0.00
"<Anonymous>"                 4.34     28.00      0.04     0.26
".External2"                  4.30     27.74      4.30    27.74
"mapply"                      4.22     27.23      0.00     0.00
"head"                        4.16     26.84      0.00     0.00
"which.min"                   4.12     26.58      2.38    15.35
"eval"                        3.16     20.39      0.00     0.00
"eval.parent"                 3.14     20.26      0.00     0.00
"write.csv"                   3.14     20.26      0.00     0.00
"format"                      2.92     18.84      0.00     0.00
"format.POSIXlt"              2.90     18.71      2.70    17.42
"do.call"                     1.78     11.48      0.00     0.00
"structure"                   1.74     11.23      0.12     0.77
"lapply"                      1.70     10.97      0.04     0.26
"FUN"                         1.66     10.71      0.00     0.00
"format.POSIXct"              1.62     10.45      0.00     0.00
"[.data.frame"                1.54      9.94      0.06     0.39
"["                           1.54      9.94      0.00     0.00
"-"                           1.30      8.39      1.30     8.39
"order"                       1.16      7.48      1.16     7.48
"rbind"                       0.94      6.06      0.04     0.26
"paste"                       0.92      5.94      0.02     0.13
"as.character"                0.90      5.81      0.08     0.52
"read.csv"                    0.84      5.42      0.00     0.00
"read.table"                  0.84      5.42      0.00     0.00
"as.character.POSIXt"         0.82      5.29      0.00     0.00
"match"                       0.58      3.74      0.58     3.74
"merge.data.frame"            0.56      3.61      0.02     0.13
"merge"                       0.56      3.61      0.00     0.00
"[<-.factor"                  0.52      3.35      0.02     0.13
"[<-"                         0.52      3.35      0.00     0.00
"strftime"                    0.48      3.10      0.00     0.00
"file"                        0.44      2.84      0.44     2.84
"weekdays"                    0.42      2.71      0.00     0.00
"weekdays.POSIXt"             0.42      2.71      0.00     0.00
"abs"                         0.40      2.58      0.40     2.58
"unique"                      0.38      2.45      0.00     0.00
"scan"                        0.30      1.94      0.30     1.94
"data.frame"                  0.22      1.42      0.14     0.90
"cbind"                       0.22      1.42      0.00     0.00
"anyDuplicated.default"       0.20      1.29      0.20     1.29
"unique.default"              0.20      1.29      0.20     1.29
"unlist"                      0.20      1.29      0.18     1.16
"anyDuplicated"               0.20      1.29      0.00     0.00
"as.POSIXct"                  0.18      1.16      0.00     0.00
"as.POSIXlt"                  0.18      1.16      0.00     0.00
"c"                           0.16      1.03      0.16     1.03
"make.unique"                 0.16      1.03      0.08     0.52
"as.POSIXct.POSIXlt"          0.12      0.77      0.12     0.77
"strptime"                    0.12      0.77      0.12     0.77
"as.POSIXlt.character"        0.12      0.77      0.00     0.00
"object.size"                 0.12      0.77      0.00     0.00
"as.POSIXct.default"          0.10      0.65      0.00     0.00
"Ops.POSIXt"                  0.08      0.52      0.00     0.00
"type.convert"                0.08      0.52      0.00     0.00
"!="                          0.06      0.39      0.00     0.00
"as.POSIXlt.factor"           0.06      0.39      0.00     0.00
"as.POSIXlt.POSIXct"          0.04      0.26      0.04     0.26
"ifelse"                      0.04      0.26      0.04     0.26
"stopifnot"                   0.04      0.26      0.02     0.13
"$"                           0.04      0.26      0.00     0.00
"$.data.frame"                0.04      0.26      0.00     0.00
"[["                          0.04      0.26      0.00     0.00
"[[.data.frame"               0.04      0.26      0.00     0.00
"head.default"                0.04      0.26      0.00     0.00
".deparseOpts"                0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
".External"                   0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"close.connection"            0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"doTryCatch"                  0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"is.na"                       0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"is.na<-.default"             0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"mean"                        0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"seq.int"                     0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"sum"                         0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"sys.function"                0.02      0.13      0.02     0.13
"%in%"                        0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
".rs.getSingleClass"          0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"[.POSIXlt"                   0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"=="                          0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"close"                       0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"data.row.names"              0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"deparse"                     0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"factor"                      0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"is.na<-"                     0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"match.arg"                   0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"match.call"                  0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"pushBack"                    0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"seq"                         0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"seq.POSIXt"                  0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"simplify2array"              0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                    0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"                0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"                 0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00
"which"                       0.02      0.13      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 15.5
```

Comment: See `help(".External2")`. `"<Anonymous>"` is an anonymous function, which was created on the fly and not assigned to a symbol. E.g., by doing `lapply(X, FUN = function(x) mean(x))` I pass an anonymous function to the `FUN` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering if there could be a reason why `write.table` is included in the total time, when I have not used this function. I have used `write.csv`, but this is shown separately in the results.

Comment: `write.csv` calls `write.table`. You see all functions there that got called.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I use `Rprof`, but I don't use `summaryRprof`. `Rprof` generates a file of stack samples, and I just examine a random selection of those. The stack samples don't have line-number information, but they do have functions, which is still useful because it give you the "why" information. If you must summarize, look at `total.pct`, which is the fraction of stack samples containing that function. self.pct is just the fraction of stack samples where that function occurs at the end. That doesn't tell you how much time the function is responsible for.